# Does Hotstar API uses statefull architecture? How does it keep track of user even if it is not login?

Tags: state, tracking, stateful

If you are watching a live cricket match on Hotstar without a login, it only allowed you to watch for five minutes. After five minutes, even if you refresh it or open in incognito mode, Hotstar does not allow you to watch.
But if I open the same website in a different computer, it again provides you five-minute span.
So what mechanism Hotstar uses to track this timespan?